# Is it possible to take away tcp port which is already listened by another program

Tags: windows, networking, port

Is it possible that some program B can take away port which is already in use (listened) by program A. Should the program A (server whitch is listening some port) actually check the port status after it opened that port?

I think that all operation with ports (open, listen, close) are implemented by operation system (Windows server 08, in this particular case). So OS won't allow any operation with port if it is occupied by another program. Am I right.

Comment: For your last paragraph, yes, the sockets/ports are held by the Operating System, in the kernel. And every OS makes a port unique to a process at any given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You could kill the other process, though.

Answer (score 1):

Old zonealarm program kind of did this.   The program probably needs some kind of Windows Kernel privilege + driver code.   Linux's SeLinux/AppArmor also do the same thing to limit the app's access to network resources.

Answer (score 0):

With sufficient OS privileges, `root` or `Administrator` equivalent, it's possible to do pretty much anything.